# TypeOf with Comparable in errors.Is

Tags: go

I am learning how error comparison works in Go and found something I cannot understand.

Function `errors.Is(err, target error)` checks if target is Comparable.

```
func Is(err, target error) bool {
    if target == nil {
        return err == target
    }

    isComparable := reflectlite.TypeOf(target).Comparable()
    for {
        if isComparable && err == target {
            return true
        }
```

[Source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/3b5eec937018be98549dea7067964018f0e5824c/src/errors/wrap.go#L45)

Which case does this call handle given that all interfaces in Go are comparable and `error` is an interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interfaces values are comparable, but the comparison can panic at run-time.  The [specification says](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> A comparison of two interface values with identical dynamic types causes a run-time panic if values of that type are not comparable.

The check prevents a panic by skipping the comparison when the target's concrete type is not comparable.

Here's an example:

```
type E []byte
func (e E) Error() string { return string(e) }
func (e E) Is(target error) bool {
    t, ok := target.(E)
    return ok && bytes.Equal(e, t)
}

var a error = E{}
var b error = E{}
fmt.Println(errors.Is(a, b)) // prints true
fmt.Println(a == b)          // panics because slices are not comparable
```

Comment: I see! Not everything that "implements" `error` interface is an error, it could be a coincidence. Nice one, thx.

Comment: @Yapaxi It is valid to implement the `error` interface using a non-comparable type.  The `Is` function must protect against this case.